# Chargebee integration with Angular 4

Tags: angular, chargebee

**Problem**:

I'm trying to integrate ChargeBee into an Angular 4 website following their simple instructions: https://jsdocs.chargebee.com/#/drop-in-checkout.

I have added within the sites tags:

And added this to a test component:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-cb-type="free">MANAGE ACCOUNT</a>
```

But when you click on the link, no errors or anything - just nothing happens.

I've checked that the library is in the header and accessible - it is. I've also tested the same code on a plain HTML page and of course it works fine. So I'm guessing it's probably something between ChargeBee's library and Angular?

I've had a look around and haven't found anything particularly useful.

Answer (score 5):

Because the `<a>` element isn't present on page load, which also means, it's not present when `ChargeBee` gets loaded, you have to call `Chargebee.registerAgain();` in `AfterViewInit`:

From within the component where your link element resides:

```
declare const Chargebee: any;

@Component({
  template: `<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-cb-type="free">MANAGE ACCOUNT</a>`
})
export class ChargeBeeComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    Chargebee.registerAgain();
  }
}
```

Comment: not working i did this  window['Chargebee'].registerAgain(); and it works

Comment: I had a typo in my declare, should work like I said as well now :)

Comment: once you fill all field how you get response when popup close?

Comment: not worked for me, used setTimeout in ngAfterViewInit worked

Comment: @TanzeelSaleem you probably did not insert the html link in the same component as where you used the `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: @PoulKruijt i did the same, my component has that HTML (anchor tag) 
but still, I need to use setTimeout to work this.